# Laravel: Factory Fake Car Data

Tags: php, laravel

I created a new factory in Laravel called "CarFactory.php" and I want to use https://github.com/pelmered/fake-car.

This is the fake data that I will insert into my database using Tinker:

```
 return [
        'name' => $this->faker->vehicleBrand(),
        'founded' => $this->faker->biasedNumberBetween(1998,2017, 'sqrt'),
        'description' => $this->faker->paragraph()
    ];
```

In the Laravel usage code, I'm not sure where to put this (e.g. Car Model, CarFactory):

```
$faker->addProvider(new \Faker\Provider\Fakecar($faker));
$v = $faker->vehicleArray();

return [
    'vehicle_type'      => 'car',
    'vin'               => $faker->vin,
    'registration_no'   => $faker->vehicleRegistration,
    'type'              => $faker->vehicleType,
    'fuel'              => $faker->vehicleFuelType,
    'brand'             => $v['brand'],
    'model'             => $v['model'],
    'year'              => $faker->biasedNumberBetween(1998,2017, 'sqrt'),
];
```

Help is needed to know how to set this up.

Comment: If you use laravel 8 can this command `php artisan make:factory CarFactory -m Car` and for model `php artisan make:model Car` laravel generate database/factories/CarFactory class. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#generating-factories